# photoshop cc 2019 saving image without background as png

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal

tried this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NDRFPZ01eE
I set up my settings like this:
[image: Click here to see the settings]

When ever i want to save my image as png i keep getting a white background even though i didn't utitlize the whole thing of my dimenions, it just fills the rest up as white background.

How can i save as png without the white background?
tried also multiple tutorials on the web but none of them really helped me or the options to select isn't in the adobe photoshop cc 2019
for example i get this when i try to save an image as png:
[image: See example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a checkbox for transparent background in the **File>Export As...** dialogue... you do have that checked, yes?

Oh, and you don't even *get* that choice if you choose **File>Quick Export As PNG** - so be sure you choose **File>Export As...** and choose .png format in the export dialogue.

[image]

Hope this helps.

P.S.

Added to address OP's comment - but with a caveat - please don't add new questions in comments - overall here at **GDSE** that's considered a faux pas.

What I addressed in the upper portion of my answer was how to get a transparent background for your .png versus a white background, as that's what you very clearly asked about - in your comment on my answer you added a secondary constraint with a misunderstanding embedded in it: that you also want a trim or crop to just the limits of your figure - and possibly when you referred to "white space" in your OP, you didn't actually mean to ask about white vs transparency, but possibly just the question of "wasted compositional space"... this, in Photoshop, is best addressed prior to exporting your composition, using the **Image>Trim... Transparent Pixels** command.

This is where that image lives:

[image]

And this is the result once this command is invoked:

[image]

Hopefully I've now addressed both the transparency issue and the wasted space issue and you should be all set to rock n' roll.

Comment: The problem is that it saves with the canvas dimension.
I just want what is inside the canvas... if you know what i mean.
for example: i only want the pentagon shape to be saved as it's own dimension and not that of the canvas dimension. if it is saved as the canvas dimension the space i didn't use in the canvas is just gonne be white background(and that is what i don't want).

Comment: @DESPRO - I added to my answer to address the additional constraint you made via comment - hope it helps.